# When build with anycpu, it has stackoverflow exception

Tags: windows-7-x64, anycpu, stack-size

I have a project it all in managed code (C# winform program). When I build in vs2010 (tried with .net 2.0 nad .net 4.03), if target with x64 or x84, they all runs greate in win 7 environment. But when build with anycpu, it has stackoverflow exception in win 7. 
It use a big stack in the logic. I have tried the following:
1) create the new thread set the size to 400000, 
2) after build run corflags xxx.exe /32BIT- 
3) run editbin xxx.exe /STACK:400000.

The problem is still there. 
Please help.

Thanks in advance.